# Highlight Field Errors with an Ajax Form

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm using a number of Ajax form, and while the I can get the error validation to work, and present the error message using the following:

```
  if (null !== form_get_errors()):
    return array(
      '#type' => 'ajax',
      '#commands' => array(
        ajax_command_remove('.alert-dismissable'),
        ajax_command_prepend('#myErrorDiv', theme('status_messages')),
      ),
    );
  endif;
```

However, I am unsure how to highlight the specific fields (usually done by adding a 'error' class to the form item.)

What the best way to achieve this, or is there a better way to handle the form errors that does not take over the normal error highlighting and message display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as hard as I thought, but for anyone else trying to solve the same issue, you need to get all the relevant fields from `form_get_errors()` and add the `error` class to the same - note I also clear the previous errors:

```
if (null !== form_get_errors()):
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#myFormDiv .form-item.error', 'removeClass', array('error'));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_remove('.alert-dismissable');
  $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#myErrorDiv', theme('status_messages'));
  foreach (form_get_errors() as $field => $message) :
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.form-item-'.$field, 'addClass', array('error'));
  endforeach;
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands,
  );   
endif;
```

Note that your `$field` will be dependent in what you've set in your validation function, so you might need to do some funky things to make sure `'.form-item-'.$field` is finding the right div.